# linking objects in blender 2.8

Tags: objects

Is there a different process for linking objects in blender 2.8? I've tried to link objects in blender 2.8 the way we used to in blender 2.79:

Go to File
Click on Link
Browse to directory(Objects) in my case I wanted to append an object.
Click on the object
Click Link from Library.

The object gets linked, but I can't move the geometry at all. What is the problem, is this a bug in blender 2.8? OR is there another method for doing this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With blender 2.83-2.90 go to *File > Append* then select the file you want to append

Then select the collection or the object you want to link and don't forget to check on the right *Instance Collections*, this will allow you to move your objects in the scene.

Answer (score 8):

You'd better just make a Proxy (Object -> Relations -> Make Proxy) or make a link duplicate of the linked object ( Duplicate Linked ).
Linked object can't be moved, but linked duplicate of linked objects can (they work just like proxies for this matter).

Answer (score 5):

The problem **WAS** literally linking an object. To be able to move the object you gotta link the collection. So, basically you have to put the object(singly) into a collection and then link it. If you have objects that don't matter when they move together, like parts of a statue that comprise a whole and don't need to be independently moved, then you can keep then in a single collection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are choosing Link instead of Append from the File menu. Append works as expected for me, i.e. I can move it and edit the mesh.

Maybe check that you have the right options ticked in the bottom left of the file browser window too (the Append from Library panel).

Comment: No, I want to link the objects, because I want them as linked instances, and it works(movable) in blender 2.79

Answer (score 1):

If you link an Object in Blender and would like to move it move it you have to make a Proxy after linking the Object. that was in 2.79 and 2.80 i think it is the same. But I didn't tried in 2.8 - because I dont link Objects I link Groups in 2.79 and as you know - now it's called Collections.

I think when you linked and moved without making Proxys in 2.79 you worked the same way.

So wanna move and instance linked objects - you have to make a Collection, put everything in that Collection and then you can link the Collection and move and Position it .