# Using Cell Fracture the object that is supposed to break, explodes or breaks before impact

Tags: animation, mesh, add-on, error

I found a lot of similar questions about the *Cell Fracture* add-on, but all with different issues.
As you will notice from the screenshots, (Blender version 2.83 LTS) between frame 125 and 126 you can see how Suzanne explodes just before the impact of the spiked ball, although she has set the *Margin* to 0.0001 as well as the shape has been set to *Mesh* and not *Convex Hull*. Below, following some tutorials, I also followed the advice to fix the bug of the chain that breaks, decreasing the *speed* and increasing the *steps per frame* and the *solver iterations* (unlike version 2.92 for example, which terms change to '' *substeps per frame* '').

Let me know and you need the file which in this case I will load it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer is to place the original (non-CF'd) model at the same location.  (use SH-S to do that if the cursor has been moved) Make the CF'd version invisible at frame 1 until the impact frame.  Make the non-CF'd (added) model visible at frame 1 and invisible at impact frame also.  This will also conceal the cracks and preserve texture until impact.
Example here - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2TaYxgtg5HPV-KU?e=1qKD5R

Comment: Thanks, now I'll try and let you know. In the gif you linked, however, the black ball disappears on impact. @Edgel3D

Comment: How do I set visibility on keyframes? @Edgel3D

Comment: That clip was actually made to answer another similar query. The ball/sphere is just scenery for that particular demo and was told to disappear. It could just as easily be made to shatter and it's own debris mixed with the cube's.

With cell fracture collisions I don't usually apply physics to the mobile object.  An invisible plane (passive rigid body, curved or otherwise) is placed inside the cube and gives me good control over where the debris is to land and how it erupts. The CF is directed to remain passive until the desired collision frame.  Cont...

Comment: ... In your case with both the monkey and ball having physics, they will interact and that's probably why the CF tends to react a little early no matter what your settings.  A simple (visual) switch from the original monkey to the CF'd one will conceal this.  To switch an object to invisible, click on it's eye and camera icons in the Outliner.  To switch it back to visible, click on them again.  Keyframe this each time by placing the cursor onto the icon and pressing ' i ' .

Comment: When i try to insert the keyframes, i get this message = "hide_viewport" property cannot be animated. @Edgel3D

Comment: also if you talked about being able to control the trajectory of the debris, you can link me some info about it I would like to understand how to do it.

Comment: That error sounds like you might be trying to hide the entire viewport, not an individual item.  That certainly wouldn't be 'keyframe-able'.  I'm using Vers 2.77 here but I'm sure I've seen posts in here where others are switching items to invisible and back with the later versions.

As for controlling cell fracture debris. Yes loose control for sure.  I can give you details but at a guess I'd say that BSE would prefer you ask a new question for that. I'll watch for it.

Comment: I was pressing on the wrong icon, anyway, I tried to do as you said but the simulation is somewhat surreal and jerky. if for example I wanted to do a slow-motion of the impact, this technique would not work. I should make it go fast enough to be unnoticeable.

Comment: If you're doing a slow-mo and segments of the cell-fracture are protruding through the original whether visible or not, that would appear quite ugly.
Is that what's happening in your case?  You can shrink those on an individual basis.

When slow-mo'd with all elements inside the original, it looks quite good no matter how slow you go - see example -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2y7YOmdJmBcAwzB?e=HZzVbf

Comment: Yes, but I need to see the impact, the collision of the two objects. not just the debris in slow-mo

Comment: Am I missing something here?  You can't just move the camera to suit?  The ball and chain etc weren't included because they were superfluous to what I was pointing out.

Comment: move the cam to do what? I do not understand. the problem is another. the impact, the collision, is not seen. and I want it to be seen. if I take a video with the cam and shoot the collision zone, it is not seen.

Comment: Look at the screenshots I put.

Comment: I take it that it's your original problem then, the ball is not contacting with the model?  Have you explored my earlier suggestion - the one where the physics is removed from the ball and propel the CF segments with an invisible rigid body 'plane' placed near the impact area?  A third and easier solution might be to use a dummy ball that's a child of the physic'd one.  Make the  latter invisible and then you can slide the new one forward to make contact with the mesh as it starts to move.  Would that suit?  I'll have to make a move here and log off....

Comment: I have adapted your previous suggestions and they have not worked well. I'll try again and let you know. I will post a gif.

Comment: Yeah good, do that, try the dummy ball also.  We're being told to move this to a chatroom so I'll do that now... God luck with it all

Comment: I've created a chat room so we can continue with this - it's here - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/121245/chat-between-edgel3d-albizz?tab=general

Comment: Perfect, thank you , so see u soon 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Cell Fracture* and physics process by default start at frame 1, and that has to be delayed.  After you do the fracture, select all segments and press  <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>  to link them all. Choose *Animation* data.

Now what you keyframe on one will affect them all.  Select one segment, set and keyframe it's physics to *Animated* at frame 1. Untick and keyframe the *Dynamic* box also.

Move the timeline to the collision frame (or there-abouts) and keyframe the boxes in reverse.  *Animated* unticked and *Dynamic* ticked.

### Addendum 1st April 2021

- One thing further to the above.  If the physics are still activating at frame 1, save the file and exit Blender.  Reload it.  This will clear the physics cache.

Apparently the procedure has been changed in vers 2.8+ and the new method is set out here - 
[linking objects in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141324/linking-objects-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: I understood your example but if you illustrated it to me with screenshots it would be easier.

Why '' Select one segment, set and keyframe it's physics to 'Animated' at frame 1 ''? If set as you say in frame 1, it all explodes at the beginning of the animation. I would say this method doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work on all segments but only on one. Do I have to set them one by one? I believe there is another method.

Comment: I tried the linking feature before I posted that comment up in the chatroom.  I've just done a search for that and apparently the procedure is different in vers 2.8+, so I've included a search link below.  For more, just search for "Linking".  There are two distinct types.  One where you can link assets from another object in a different Blend file, and the 2nd where you do as I suggested, link several existing objects together.  If you can't manage what you'll read in the link below, - (see next comment)

Comment: Cont... There is a workaround that should bypass the new system and force Blender to link the segments regardless but see how you go with this first... see the last answer given there - 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141324/linking-objects-in-blender-2-8

Comment: Perfect, after several tests and several connections, I was able to set keyframes for all CF debris. since we are on the subject, observing the animation, the ball in the moment of impact, has a small recoil but I think it is due to the weight I have attributed to my objects. Also to make a change of this kind must necessarily run clean keyframes, from scratch. Because otherwise everything blows up like a bomb. lol

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You're welcome Albizz.  Glad you got it going!  :)