# Rigid Bodies instantly jump around upon starting the animation

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a fractured object (pic 1) and on all of the fractures, I have a rigid body animation (settings in pic 2). The problem I'm facing is: as soon as I start the animation, all the fractures with the rigid bodies instantly start jumping around instead of just sitting there (they're on top of a plane with a passive rigid body setting on it). **Why is this happening?**
[image]
[image]

Comment: By jumping around do you mean fly everywhere and explode, or just bounce up and down?

Comment: @LWSSWL Jumping around. They don't go crazy. They just move around and I can't have them doing that.

Comment: You can prevent the fracture segments from activating until the frame where that's required...

Take a look at the answer here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215746/using-cell-fracture-the-object-that-is-supposed-to-break-explodes-or-breaks-bef/217727#217727

Comment: You probably should avoid using “mesh” shape when doing rigid bodies. It has an inherent margin and is not as precise as “convex hull”.

Comment: @TheLabCat: The mesh is the most precise thing you can do with rigid bodies. The convex hull does only work good on simple shapes which have no holes or indentations. Here you can see an example [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9miL.gif: left: convex hull, right: mesh. Same collision margins. The convex hull doesn't "recognize" the indentation. Maybe read this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/convex_hull.html

Comment: @ProEffectsMAX: it can be more than one reason why this happens. If you provide your blend file, we can say which reason it is. e.g. Overlapping geometries, too big margins...etc.

Comment: @TheLabCat: did you look at my video? stack these cubes and it is 1000x better. Now promote me!!!

Comment: or do you mean by "stability" just unrealistic!?

Comment: @TheLabCat : that’s why I wrote: convex hull only works on simpel shapes….